# How to map React components but have 2 different sources of info

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Hi I want to render information about schools and also upload an image of the schools/programs

I have image URLs and information in different state since the images are saved on S3 while the information is in postgres. As a result, I have 2 different routes.

Since the map function only allows for one item how can I access both pieces of information to render the component?

React

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function requestSchools() {
            await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/getschool").then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setSchools(response.data.rows)
            })

            await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/getschoolimages").then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setImageKey(response.data.Contents)
            })
        }
        requestSchools();

        let doubleArr = [[], []]
        doubleArr[0].push(schools)
        doubleArr[1].push(imageKey)

        console.log('doubleArr', doubleArr)

        setSchools(doubleArr);

        return schools
    }, []);

    console.log('schools Correct', schools)


    //console.log(schools)


    const renderSchools = (school, index) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <InfoCard
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    name={school.name}
                    about={school.about}
                    location={school.location}
                    admission={school.admission}
                    identifier={index + 1}
                    url={imageKey[index]}

                />
            </div>

        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/additem">
                <button className="ret_btn">Create</button>
            </Link>
            <div>{schools.map(renderSchools)}</div>
        </div>

    )
```

Backend

```
schoolRouter.get('/getschool', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const allschools = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM school`);
        console.log('allschools', allschools.rows)
        const imageKeys = s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log('error', err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else console.log(data);
        })
        res.json(allschools)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }

})




schoolRouter.get('/getschoolimages', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        //console.log('allschools', allschools.rows)
        const imageKeys = s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log('error', err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else res.send(data);
        })
        //res.json(allschools)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }

})
```

Infocard

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../stylesheets/cardstyles.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';



const InfoCard = (props) => {
    const url = `https://dreamschools-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/${props.url}`
    return (
        <div className="container spacer">
            <div className="row align-items-center gen-card">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-6"><img width="100%" alt="Grandfather with child" src={url} sizes="(max-width: 200x) 80vw, 200px" /></div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 gen-card">
                    <h3>{props.name}</h3>
                    <p>{props.about}</p>


                    <Link to={{
                        pathname: `/allinfo/${props.identifier}`,
                        param1: {
                            name: props.name,
                            about: props.about,
                            location: props.location,
                            admission: props.admission,
                            id: props.identifier
                        }
                    }}>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary my-3 btn-block">More information</button>
                    </Link>

                    <Link to={{
                        pathname: `/edititem/${props.identifier}`,
                        param1: {
                            name: props.name,
                            about: props.about,
                            location: props.location,
                            admission: props.admission,
                            id: props.identifier
                        }
                    }}>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary my-3 btn-block">Edit</button>
                    </Link>

                    {/*  <a className="btn btn-primary my-3 btn-block" href="/contact/">Edit</a> */}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default InfoCard
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `image` as a property of the `school` objects, something like:

```
// it looks like you have the same order in both since I see you have `imageKey[idx]` in your example
const schoolsWithImage = schools.map((school, idx) => {...school, image: images[idx]})

setSchools(schoolsWithImage)
```

then you can do `school.image` when looping.

Comment: I am sorry but what does the ... mean exactly, I get the error declaration or statement expected

Comment: ... is the spread operator in javascript. It takes all the elements of the variable object mentioned after it and spreads it in the assigned variable on the left side

Comment: The syntax is incorrect and that might be causing an error. To directly return a JavaScript object from a map function we must wrap it inside parenthesis:

const schoolsWithImage = schools.map((school, idx) => ({...school, image: images[idx]}))

Comment: yes, sorry, it's missing the `( )` around the object

Answer (score 0):

if the order is correct you could just use index as key to get the correct value, if the order is incorrect you would have to have a shared identifier with the most effective way being doing one loop and merge corresponding objects, or a very ineffective way would be to find the correct image for every iteration within your map, it would give you "cleaner" code but would result in a extra loop for every iteration of your map. Whilst  first one is little more code but alot more effective.

And change your async function

```
let school = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/getschool")

let schoolimages = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/getschoolimages")
 setSchools(school.data.rows)
 setImageKey(schoolimages.data.Contents)
```

test that and tell me how it goes

Comment: the order is correct and did use try to pass it into my code but I keep getting undefined when I pass the index

Comment: i might be wrong but you dont use `then` with await? updated my answer try it out and tell me how it goes, this will wait for both awaits promises to be fullfilled before you setstates and which insures that both states have been defined